# Java Regex Find all Placeholders "{}" within Placeholders

Tags: java, regex

I got a problem that I've been working on a few days now and really can't find the answer to...
I believe it to be simple but I can't find it...
I have looked all over Google and havn't found anything that can help me with this (perhaps I don't know what to search for?)

Note: In text Placeholder is anything within {}

So my Problem:
I have a String:
"{Prefix} {playerLeave}"

With regex I need to find the {Prefix} replace it with a value and then check the new value if it has a placeholder and so forth.

In this instance it would go like this:

2. "{Prefix} {playerLeave}"
3. "[Conquest] You have left {kingdom}"
4. "[Conquest] You have left Celestra"

What I've tried (and gotten furthest with) is:

```
private static String translate(String text){
    try{

        while(text.matches("\\{(.*?)\\}")){
            Matcher match = Pattern.compile("\\\b{(.*?)\\}\b").matcher(text);
            while (match.find()) {
                text = match(match.group(), text);
            }
        }
        if (text.matches("\\{(.*?)\\}"))
            translate(text);
        return text;
    }catch(Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
        Bukkit.getConsoleSender().sendMessage(getMessage("&4ERROR: &cA placeholder failed!"));
        return "";
    }
}       

private static String match(String match, String text){
    text = text.contains("{Prefix}")    ? text.replace(match, String.valueOf(Cach.Prefix))              
    text = text.contains("{TeleportDelay}")     ? text.replace(match, String.valueOf(Cach.tpDelay))                                     : text.replace(match, "");
    text = text.contains("{town}")                  ? text.replace(match, String.valueOf(Cach.StaticTown.getName()))            : text.replace(match, "");
    text = text.contains("{village}")                   ? text.replace(match, String.valueOf(Cach.StaticVillage.getName()))         : text.replace(match, "");
    text = text.contains("{kingdom}")               ? text.replace(match, String.valueOf(Cach.StaticKingdom.getName()))         : text.replace(match, "");
    text = text.contains("{color}")                     ? text.replace(match, Cach.StaticKingdom.getColorSymbol())                  : text.replace(match, "");
    return text;
}
```

Issue is it's working to a degree it work's until stage
2. "[Conquest] You have left {kingdom}"
And if I debug it it sais:
text.matches("\{(.*?)\}") is false in this block of code:

```
if (text.matches("\\{(.*?)\\}"))
            translate(text);
```

Thanks in advance!

Regards,
Thomas

Comment: Your question is unclear. Do you want to just replace all placeholders, or do you want recursive replacement? E.g. if value of `Prefix` is `ab{c}de`, first iteration would change `{Prefix} {playerLeave}` to `ab{c}de {playerLeave}`, but do you then want `{c}` replaced with value of `c`, or do you just want next *original* placeholder, i.e. `{playerLeave}`, to be processed? And what if input is `{a}b}` and `a = "{x"`, then you get `{xb}`, so does that mean you want that replaced with value of `xb`?

Comment: Why can't you use `String.replace()`?  It does what you want and with less rigamarole than your regex code.

Comment: I solved my issue I was over complicating it and thanks to @Andreas I saw it while looking for the answer to the question he said.

I was merly collecting a text from an array and what I didn't actualy thought of was that I only had one word (the placeholder) in said text so it would be a straightforward replace.

Answer (score 0):

There is an error in this regex `Pattern.compile("\\\b{(.*?)\\}\b")`: last `\b` have only one back slash.

And again, you say:

> I need to find the {Prefix} replace it with a value

But the group in this line matches only the text within the curly braces (i.e. *Prefix*)

So all the matches you find, contains groups that are without the curly braces.

The `text.replace(match, ... )` executed later by the function `match` will replace only the text within the curly braces.

If I get what's in your mind, I suggest to change that line into:

```
Pattern.compile("(\\{[^\\}]*\\})")
```